# Is it possible to set field values from object using TypeOrm?

Tags: typescript, orm, typeorm

Is it possible to set field values from object using TypeOrm preserving type safity?

All examples I found in the documentation suggest you to set properties one-by-one

```
const newUser = new User();
newUser.firstName = 'John'
newUser.lastName = 'Doe'
newUser.role = 'manager'
newUser.phone = '1234567890'
newUser.login = 'john.doe'
newUser.password = '12345'
newUser.save();
```

It would be much nicer if I could set fields this way:

```
const newUser = new User();
newUser.setFields({
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe',
        role: 'manager',
        phone: '1234567890',
        login: 'john.doe',
        password: '12345'
    }
);
newUser.save();
```

It would allow to use shortcuts

```
const newUser = new User();
newUser.setFields({
        firstName,
        lastName,
        role,
        phone,
        login: 'john.doe',
        password: '12345'
    }
);
newUser.save();
```

And use composition

```
const newUser = new User();
newUser.setFields({
        firstName,
        lastName,
        role,
        phone,
        ...credentials
    }
);
newUser.save();
```

though I could not find any way to do so.

I understand that by you need to have a type describing shape of your object in order to achieve it but I was hoping TS/TsOrm can derive it somehow from models I define.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `create` and `merge` method of an entity or repository (depending on your implementation) will be what you're looking for most likely:

```
const userEntity = UserEntity.create({ firstName, lastName, ...someOtherStuff });
const mergedEntity = UserEntity.merge(mergedEntity, { lastName: "new last name" });
```

For further information consult the [documentation](https://typeorm.io/#/repository-api) and scroll down to the mentioned methods which includes the following samples:

```
const user = repository.create(); // same as const user = new User();
const user = repository.create({
    id: 1,
    firstName: "Timber",
    lastName: "Saw"
}); // same as const user = new User(); user.firstName = "Timber"; user.lastName = "Saw";

const user = new User();
repository.merge(user, { firstName: "Timber" }, { lastName: "Saw" });
// same as user.firstName = "Timber"; user.lastName = "Saw";
```